# How to call php webservice url in SAPUI5?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-web-ide

I have tried various methods for this but I didn't get this one, can anyone give a proper solution for this? Actually, I know how to call a web service by using ajax calls, but whenever I try to pass my url as below, it gives me the following error:

```
onInit: function() {

    $.ajax({
        url:"http://SERVER_IP/SAP_DEMO/register.php",
        type: "POST",
        datatype:"json",
        accepts:{ text:"application/json" },
        success: function(oResData){
            if(!oResData) {
                sap.m.MessageToast.show("No Success"); 
            }
            else { sap.m.MessageToast.show(" Success"); } 
        },
        error: function() { sap.m.MessageToast.show("unsuccessful json call"); } 
    });

    var oModel=new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel); 
}
```

The above code gives me this error:

> error: Fiori Architectural guidelines: ESLint(sap-no-hardcoded-url): Hardcoded (non relative) url found.

Answer (score 0):

In the docu [here](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/webide/frameset.htm?fa158d772a2a48bc9b1530713ac03bbd.html) it says:
“sap-no-hardcoded-url:
Use of hardcoded URLs is not allowed.
SAP Fiori guidelines do not allow usage of hardcoded URLs to internal or external systems.
Rule Details:
Instead of references to internal systems in your URLs, you should only reference the path to the resource.”

You need to define the destination in a separate step as seen in [this blog](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3901519).